# Google API - How do I get alias emails for a user?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-apps, google-domain-api

**Question**

Using Google Apps OAuth for authentication, how can I retrieve a user's email aliases?

I can't seem to find any API docs on how to do this. What are the necessary scopes and what is the correct call to get that info?

**Why**

Let's say I have a user Alice that invites `bob@company.com` to use the app. Unfortunately, `bob@company.com` is actually an alias for `bob.jones@company.com`. When Bob logs into the service with Google OAuth, Google tells me his email address is `bob.jones@company.com`. Now I have accidentally created two accounts for Bob when I want to recognize them as the same account.

Comment: related (check the question comments) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870445/get-all-email-addresses-of-user-using-google-api

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Google People API for this. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/requests). The scope you need to use is: 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read

This will return all the email addresses for the user and also tell you which is the primary one.

Comment: NOTE: The correct scope for reading access to the authenticated user's email addresses is: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read`